# How to create floating button or window like facebook messenger in android

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I need to create a floating button within a service.  But I have no idea about this. Please can anyone post a way to create a  floating button?

Comment: Try google "android floating chat heads", here is an example: http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/

Comment: @nvi9, thank you for your good help. Can you help me a little bit? Can you tell me how to add action to that imageviw according to your given link tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Inflate a view using LayoutManager and add this view to WindowManager.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support only post-Lolipop devices for your application you can use the standard [FloatingActionButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) from android library.

However if you want to support pre-Lolipop or have some extra functionality i suggest you go through some external libraries.

Most of the external libraries can be found at [Android Aresnal - FAB](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/173).

Using them in your project is pretty straight forward.

Currently i'm using [android-floating-action-button](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/965).It is a pretty decent library with some nice functions.